# Firebase hosting rewrite to an external url

Tags: firebase, url-rewriting, firebase-hosting

I am building an app using firebase that needs to load an external webpage under an internal url i.e. when you go to myapp.com/edit it requests the content from someotherapp.com/edit and renders it in the browser without redirecting. I've tried using firebase hosting rewrites, but you can only rewrite to an internal url or a cloud function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing cannot be accomplished with rewrites, as those (as you say) can only rewrite to a location on the same server.

A redirect would allow you to redirect to a different server, but that new URL is then sent to the browser.

The only alternative option is to use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) or [Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run) to capture all requests, read from the remote server in that code, and then send that back to the client with a [suitable caching interval](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache).